# Extending TinyMCE Wordpress Plugin with more plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce

I want to extend TinyMCE Advanced Wordpress Plugin with one of the plugins that is written for original tinymce editor package (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). That plugin is imgmap and I can find some steps (www.code.google.com/p/imgmap/wiki/TinyMCE_setup) to setup this plugin with original tinymce editor, but tinymce advanced wordpress plugin seems different.

Can anyone please guide me how can do?

Comment: accept more answers by clicking on the green check mark so people are motivated to answer you.